# how to read an external .ini file in a batch script and use the key value in the script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .ini file with key,value pairs and want to call it via a batch script. I can use a `SET` directly in the batch file but i would like to keep a external ini file.
Like in Bash scripting , where i can do an EXPORT and then can use the keys as `${key}` for fetching the values, what can be the approach in batch scripting.

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How does your ini file look like? what's the code, you have problems with? Which problems? What does it do and what should it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Your_ini_file.ini) do set %%a
```

then just use `%key%` to retrieve the value of the desired key in the code.

If you have a key pair :

```
color=#ff0000
```

then you'll have the variable `%color%` setted with the value `#ff0000`

Comment: That would start the program associated with the ini extension. Either: **1** add type in front of Your_ini_file.ini or **2** remove the single quotes or **3** change the single quotes to double ones and add usebackq.